# I'm trying to make a pokemon style levelup progress bar, but I've run into an issue with my logic on how it's using remaining xp to level up

Tags: c#

I'm having a very difficult time trying to wrap my head around this situation.

```
EarnedXP = 1000
PlayerXPMax = 20
PlayerLevelUp = 1

for (int x = EarnedXP; x != 0; PlayerXPMax - x)
   PlayerLevelUp++;
```

I am attempting to setup a levelup problem. I want to give the player any amount of xp, despite the maximum allowed. When the maximum is hit, the player gains a level, and xp is reset to 0. After hitting 0, the remaining xp is tossed back through the same statement and if again, the remaining xp is greater than the players maximum, it uses the remainder of that, and grants yet another level to the player.

The biggest problem I'm having is using a remainder equation inside the for statement. It's just not making any sense to me.

In the program itself, I'm using several progress bars to hold my values, such as maximum, and current value. I kind of want a pokemon style level up, where it hits full, dings, then fills up again, until the remaining xp is gone.

I'm trying to do this compactly, and cramming it all into like 5 lines in a for statement.

All variables being used by the program for this particular problem:

```
playerxp.maximum //This is the maximum xp my player can attain per level
playerxp.value //current xp the player has
earnedxp //xp gained from slaughtering the poor little ladybugs
playerlevel.value //the level of the player currently not doing anything but its there
```

I'm also updating all information into a consolebox that I custom made.

```
private void addPlayerXP(int earnedXP)
{
    int remainder = 0;
    while (earnedXP >= playerXP.Maximum)
    {
        remainder = (earnedXP - playerXP.Maximum);
        playerXP.Value += remainder;
        consoleOutput.AppendText((earnedXP - playerXP.Maximum).ToString() + "\r\n");
        consoleOutput.AppendText(xpNotifier());
        if (playerXP.Value == playerXP.Maximum)
        {
            consoleOutput.AppendText("DING\r\n");
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(playerLevel.Text);
            playerLevel.Text = temp++.ToString();
            playerXP.Value = 0;
        }
        earnedXP -= playerXP.Maximum;
        consoleOutput.AppendText(earnedXP.ToString() + "\r\n");
    }
```

Exected outcome: Player gains 1000 xp. required xp for level up = 60. Player gains 60 xp, levels up xp back to 0, level up + 1. Remaining 9940 xp is added repeatedly until remaining xp is less then maximum xp for level up.

Current outcome: player gains 100xp, max xp is 60. Player levels up, but is not displayed as it should be. Player now has 40 xp. Player gains another 100 xp, program crashes because the loop only runs once it seems like.

Comment: After you edit it's quite unclear what the problem is. Please indicate what you're trying to achieve, what you're having a problem with, and what the expected output is.

Comment: Ok, lemme edit again Gimme a moment

Comment: your `if` condition has an assignment (`=`) instead of a comparison (`==`). My answer already covers what you're trying to do, what about it doesn't apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I completely understood your problem, but I believe this is what you want:

```
while (PlayerXP >= PlayerXPMax)
{
    PlayerLevelUp++;
    PlayerXP -= PlayerXPMax;
}
```

And without a loop, this would look like:

```
int numLevels = PlayerXP / PlayerXPMax; //Assuming both variables are ints!
PlayerLevelUp += numLevels;
PlayerXP -= numLevels * PlayerXPMax;
```

The big problem with your for loop is that nothing is happening in the final term which should change a state that affects the loop condition. You write `PlayerXPMax - x` but that is an expression, it never affects the result of `x != 0`.

Comment: I will test this and see if the outcome appears to be what I'm after. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I've tested it out, and have realized that my problem is much more in depth then just a few variables. I'll update my main post mentioning all of my variables that come into play in the particular problem

Comment: Rotem - this is what @JohnOlivas is asking about - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13638/algorithm-for-dynamically-calculating-a-level-based-on-experience-points (basically write a loop over XP needed for each level till there is enough for next level)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe so, but in the OPs code it seems the XP required to level up is constant.

Comment: At the moment the xp is constant, as I'm in a very small testing/planning phase right now, I do later plan on making it require more xp per level eventually @Rotem

Comment: "Pokemon style level up" - I don't think OP actually knows exactly what they want for XP needed for each level. Exponential growth for each level is quite standard... Indeed they can pick constant cost but code would be the same.

Comment: @JohnOlivas To be fair to this answer, it actually ticked all the boxes of the original question. *"I will test this and see if the outcome appears to be what I'm after. Thanks"* always rings warning bells. You need to scope your questions correctly the first time so they can be answered, and if you have additional problems you should ask a better question (not just edit it with entirely different scope)

Comment: @TheGeneral More so, I don't see how the testing and subsequent edit changed anything in the original intent of the question. All it did was rename the variables. As far as I see, the answer still applies.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm just trying to get this thing to loop until I run out of earnedxp. When I earn more xp, use current xp vs earnedxp and loop until theres not enough left again. the more I mess with it, the more confusing it gets

Comment: @JohnOlivas What doesn't work for you with my answer?

Comment: the max xp and current value xp are being used in the same problem. I have 
    xp.value and     xp.maximum. Value is what I'm adding     earnedXp to, and using the maximum as the most     earnedXp per operation. Currently I'm doing increments of 140 earned xp, and it does the loop correctly, but I still have 20 xp left over which I want to give to player. When that carries over into the next battle, it either crashes or doesn't keep that 20 xp at all

Comment: @JohnOlivas First add `earnedXp` to the player's total XP, and then apply the algorithm mentioned in the answer. Think of them as poker chips. The xp counter represents $1 chips, and the level counter represents $60 chips. You're just converting one type from the other.

Comment: When I add earnedxp straight to the playerxp.value it causes the program to crash as the playerxp.maximum is 60. Which is why im using the remainder thing so it doesn't crash it as soon as it tries to add the xp[

Comment: @JohnOlivas So copy it to a temporary variable.